# jquery selecting previous or next element among the matched elements

Tags: jquery

i have a set of divs in which the first div has width and height.
what i need is selecting all the divs and then set it's width and height by adding 50 px to the previous div.
for example, if the 1st one is 100px width and 75 height, then the second div should be 150px x 125 and next one is 200x175 and so on.
in jquery, i used $("div").each(....) to go through the elements ... but need to retrieve the width and height of the previous selected element(not previous sibling!)
help me to do it.........
thanks

Comment: Could you show what you've written so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do something like this:

```
var previousHeight = 75;
var previousWidth = 100;
$("div").each(function () {
  $(this).height(previousHeight);
  $(this).width(previousWidth);
  previousHeight += 50;
  previousWidth += 50;
});
```

No need to have the previous div if you are already keeping track of the previous height. Just a thought!

**JSFiddle** - Just for a quick example I put together a JSFiddle with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/mFTQa/

Comment: thanks guy you are correct..........but is there any method to travel between selected element in jquery like next(), previous() in sibling?

Comment: @pradeep You can traverse nodes or you can save the previous value of the "each" (basically the same as how I answered the question) or even store the results of the $("div") query in an array and then traverse in any order you want. It all comes down to your goals. Hope this helps!

Comment: Drew, I am not sure why the down-voted you.  Your answer is correct, plus I like that you took the time to create a JSFiddle